# Can't get UI to work

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to learn the UI Service in order to build my own form (panel). I tried copying and running the example panel, but I can't get it to work (the code is below). The panel will not pop up. Do I have to set something in my browser? Please help.

```
function doGet() { 
// A script with a user interface that is published as a web app
// must contain a doGet(e) function.

// Create the UiInstance object myapp and set the title text
var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Here is the title bar');

// Create a button called mybutton and set the button text
var mybutton = myapp.createButton('Here is a button');

// Create a vertical panel called mypanel and add it to myapp
var mypanel = myapp.createVerticalPanel();

// Add mybutton to mypanel
mypanel.add(mybutton);

// Add my panel to myapp
myapp.add(mypanel);

// return myapp to display the UiInstance object and all elements associated with it.
return myapp;

}
```

Comment: How are you trying this code?  Have you been through the version/deploy requirements?

Comment: You have to access your script from the it's published URL, it does not just pops up when you run it manually.

Comment: Read the documentation here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web?hl=fr-FR

Answer (score 0):

The `doGet()` function runs when the URL of your App is either first loaded in the browser, **OR** you refresh the page in your browser.  If your App is a **Stand Alone** App (Not attached to a Sheet or a Doc) then you will have a file associated with that app in your Google Drive.  The Apps Script file icon is a blue square with a white arrow pointing to the right.

[image: Apps Script File in Drive]

If you double click that file, it should open up in your browser and run the `doGet()` function.  You can also provide the URL of the App as a link.

But first you need to deploy it.

Click the icon of a cloud with an up arrow in it:

[image: Apps Script Code Editor]

You'll be asked to name your project if you haven't done that already.  Then, you'll get a pop up that looks like this:

[image: Deploy As Web App]

Click **Deploy**

You'll get another pop up, . . . click 'Latest Code'.  Your app will open up in the browser.

The code you supplied puts a button in the window labeled, 'Here is a Button'.